# Centos 7 not booting from Dell Perc 6i raid 0

Tags: centos7, dell-poweredge

I recently obtained a poweredge 2900 (unknown generation) tower with a perc 6i controller and built and initalize a raid 0 array from 2 146gb sas drives. During the centos installation it does see and install to the virtual drive, but after a reboot the server complains that it cannot find a boot device.

Does this have something to do with the Perc 6i firmware (1.21.02 I think) or centos incapable of booting from the virtual disk?

IMAGES:

[Boot sequence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MM5oA.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You should set your VD to be bootable via PERC BIOS, there's an option to select Bootable VD under `Ctrl Mgmt` menu.

Comment: I did set the VD as bootable but the issue is still occuring.

Comment: If VD is bootable under PERC BIOS, next thing to check if it is enabled as bootable device under main BIOS, there should be an entry for PERC and it should be enabled and placed above other devices in boot sequence..

Comment: Oddly, I did not find the perc option in the BIOS, so could the bios be too old?

Comment: Enter PERC BIOS and check to see if Controller BIOS is set to Enable under Settings box in Ctrl Mgmt.

Comment: That was also enabled too, still no sucess.

Comment: When BIOS initializes, there should be a message regarding x logical drives detected, y logical drives are handled by BIOS. What does it say in your case?

Comment: "1 virtual drive found on host adapter" "1 virtual drive handled by BIOS"

Comment: So the drive is there in the BIOS list, so it definitively should be available as an option in boot devices list within main BIOS. If you press F9 to enter boot selection menu, is it there?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no option for virtual disk in the boot menu.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your Boot Sequence, Hard Drive Sequence and Integrated Devices within F2 BIOS?

Comment: Just edited my post with two pictures (cant add more because I don't have enough reputation).

Comment: Boot sequence and hard drive boot sequence are two menus in F2 BIOS right above Integrated devices, that's what we need to see..

Comment: Sorry, did not read correctly, just redited the post. I could not find the hard drive boot sequence, however.

Comment: Well, its weird. My only advice would be to update a firmware, clear CMOS and reset raid config, and if it won't help try moving the card to a different slot.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the server BIOS to the current (as of this writing, 2.7.0):

http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/956/t/19545459

Also, there are a large number of firmware and backplane updates for this server:

http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/poweredge-2900/drivers?os=rh60

Applying all of these (yes, I know, very tedious) may get you past this problem. Good luck!